# Two color mode for emacs - no colors / monochrome

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp

I dont like colors. How can I tell emacs to
stick to just black and white for everything.

Higlighted text or the mode line can be
shown in reverse video (black text on white background)

I'm using Emacs 24 on windows under cygwin
in console mode.

I tried,
TERM=xterm-mono emacs --no-splash
which gives
emacs: Terminal type xterm-mono is not defined.

Also
emacs --no-splash --reverse-video
which  shows some blues and some other colors too.

I already have the following in my .emacs:

```
(setq-default global-font-lock-mode nil)
(set-face-foreground 'mode-line "white")
(set-face-background 'mode-line "black")
```

M-x customize-face seems interesting but there's about
300 lines of options and I dont feel like changing that
many lines.

Comment: A little late, but `emacs --color=never` seems to work for me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I don't like colors very much either, but the way I did it is to only change those faces that bothered me.  I.e. go to a chunk of text with a color you don't like, then use `M-x customize-face` there (which should give you as default the face used for that color) and change that one (or if it inherits from another, you might prefer to change the one from which it inherits).

While there are hundreds of faces, in my experience, you can start by changing a small dozen.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling [`font-lock`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html) should get rid of most colours. Try this in your configuration:

```lisp
(global-font-lock-mode -1)
```

I don't have Cygwin to test on, but it gives me white on black in a Linux terminal with `emacs -nw`.